# Can I run the net native tool chain after a compilation?

Tags: uwp, msbuild, windows-10-universal

We compile certain UWP application in release|x64 that profit by compiling them with `/p:UseDotNetNativeToolchain=true`
The issue with this is the fact that .net native optimization is slow, very slow.

Now I've read an older article stating that the native tool chain starts after the creation of the MSIL code and builds on top of it.

Our .net native tool chain recently became very flaky (compiling it once fails on a machine, clean building it on the same machine again sometimes then works).

My question is: Is there a known way of compiling an UWP in release without native and then call the .net native tool chain on top.
My intention here is to split both parts and rerun only the net native tool chain when it fails, without running the entire compilation again.

Basically the steps would be

```
msbuild .\App1.sln /t:Rebuild /property:"Configuration=Release"  /property:Platform=x64 /m /v:minimal /p:UseDotNetNativeToolchain=false

# cache the results of this process

msbuild <the cached files> with /p:UseDotNetNativeToolchain=false
```

Unfortunately even if I do not rebuild the second step and just call `/t:Build` the entire chain is starting from source again (without moving any binaries for 'caching').

So if somebody has an idea how I can post-process MSIL into net native binaries I would be very thankful :)

Comment: That's a fundamental misunderstanding of what .NET-native is all about.  It models what the store server does after it accepted your UWP package.  Which is error-prone, doing it on your machine ensures the package is in good order and the server does not reject it.  In other words, it makes no sense to skip, delay or repeatedly try it.  The server does not do anything like it, this needs to compile cleanly in a single try.

Comment: @HansPassant I had this article in mind https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-net-native-tool-chain/
It states Step 1 is building MSIL from source and Step 2-7 is basically ILC. So I hoped to separate those steps